# Open source flashlight app?

Tags: open-source

On my new phone, for security reasons I decided to stick to Open Source apps as much as possible.

Is there an Open Source flashlight app?

The most popular flashlight apps ([1](https://market.android.com/details?id=goldenshorestechnologies.brightestflashlight.free),[2](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.devuni.flashlight)) are asking for crazy permissions: GPS, camera, Internet, GPS, SD card...

If no Open Source is available, at least one I would be happy with a very simple one, such as [this one](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.dyndns.devesh.flashlight) (white screen, brightness 100%, lock screen) which for some reason is not available for my new [phone](http://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_u8150_ideos-3513.php).

Comment: Are you running the stock ROM on your handset?  The flashlight app that's built into CyanogenMod 7.x is most definitely open source, but it will only work with CM7 installed.  http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1001132

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Search Light](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.scottmain.android.searchlight/) is [open source](https://code.google.com/p/search-light/), has no unnecessary permissions, and has a nice set of operating modes.

Comment: Very nice! Too bad my phone does not have a camera flash, I really should have mentioned this. Accepting though, because your answer is correct.

Comment: I just submitted it to the F-Droid repository: http://f-droid.org/forums/topic/search-light/

Answer (score 2):

[OI Flashlight](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.openintents.flashlight/) is Open Source, it can use both camera flash and bright screen.

Answer (score 0):

*Kevin's answer is great, but just some new info:*

The **Flashlight** app, which was popular since very early on, has been released as Open Source:

https://github.com/devesh/Flashlight